# Simple Ajax not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small script that sends single value to php file, its working in Firefox but not on Chrome and IE

jQuery

```
var i=1;
$.post("../asset/view/check.php",{i:i},function(data){
    alert('hi');
});
```

Javascript

```
var i=1;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      alert('hi');
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "../asset/view/check.php?i="+i+"", false);
xhttp.send();
```

Can you see why this is not working?

Comment: Unless you show complete code, can't say what could the problem. The URL seems to be relative, **try absolute URL**

Comment: *"Please see why this is not working."*, you're not doing your best here. The code looks good, check your console or network tab.

Comment: Have you checked XMLHttpRequest exists on all those browsers? depending on the type/version, it could be a bit different.

Comment: Your jQuery code has issue. Replacing {i:i} to {'i':i} will work..javascript working fine